# Three.js WebGL animation exhibits ghosting in web view on Android 5.1.1 Lollipop

Tags: javascript, android, three.js, webgl, augmented-reality

I'm using WebGL and three.js to build an augmented reality app. I want to use a transparent web view with WebGL to show 3D content overlaid on a video feed. The problem is I'm getting bad ghosting effects when I set the WebGLRenderer to be transparent by passing it `alpha: true` to the `WebGLRenderer` constructor.

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var canvas = document.getElementById("webGLCanvas");
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, alpha: true });
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    cube.position.z = -5;
    scene.add( cube );

    render();

    function render()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

When the animation of the spinning cube runs, it looks like this:

[image: spinning cube with ghosting]

If I don't pass `alpha: true` to the `WebGLRenderer` constructor, the ghosting problem goes away, but then my canvas and web view are not transparent.

Is this a bug in Chrome/WebView on Android Lollipop, or is there some better way to do this?

EDIT: I should mention that this same code does not have the ghosting problem when running in a web view on iOS 8+.

Comment: This is from OpenGL, so I assume it's possible in WebGL, but you should clear the color buffer before rendering each frame. Can you confirm you're doing this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but adding `renderer.clear()` right before `renderer.render(scene, camera)` did not make a difference. Also setting `renderer.autoClear = true` or `renderer.autoClearColor = true` did not help.

Comment: I thought WebGL allowed you to call OpenGL functions? For example, can you not `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` or equivalent --e.g. `glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, ...);`?

Comment: I have some doubts about having WebGL in a WebView alpha composited over a video feed (TextureView/SurfaceView). I do recommend listening to the WebView episode of Android Backstage: http://androidbackstage.blogspot.com/2015/11/episode-37-webview.html and perhaps submit a bug report to: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry?template=Webview%20Bugs

Comment: Per your suggestion, I tried `renderer.context.clear(renderer.context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)` which perhaps interacts with the GL context more directly, but to no avail.

Comment: I have been unable to reproduce this problem in Chrome on the same device. It seems to only happen in the web view in an app. Perhaps Morrision Chang is right about this being a compositing issue.